# Differences between the limit points of a sequence and the limit points of range the sequence?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Here are my definitions of a limit point of a set and a sequence:

1. $l \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of a real sequence $\left(x_n\right) \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon >0, x_n \in \left(l- \epsilon, l + \epsilon \right)$ for infinitely many values of $n$.
2. $l \in \mathbb{R}$ is a limit point of a set $S \Leftrightarrow \forall \, \epsilon >0, \left(\left(l-\epsilon, l+\epsilon\right)\cap S\right) \setminus \{l\}≠ \varnothing$

---

With that being said, I want to specifically talk about the case when $S$ is the range of $(x_n)$, i.e. $S= \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}$

> **Question 1:** What is the difference between the definition of limit points of $(x_n)$ and $S$?

For starters, I can see that the definition $1$ allows $l$ to be a limit point even if $(l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon)\cap S = \{l\}$, a singleton set while definition $2$ ensures the intersection $(l-\epsilon, l+\epsilon)\cap S$ be an infinite set for $l$ to be a limit point. But what else? Is that really the only difference?

> **Question 2:** Can I restate the definition $2$ for range of $(x_n)$ as: $l$ is a limit point of $S= \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N}\}
>  \Leftrightarrow \forall \epsilon >0, x_n \in (l-\epsilon,l+\epsilon) \setminus \{l\}$ for infinitely many values of $n$?

In light of the question $2$, would it be correct to say: If $l$ is a limit point of S then $l$ is a limit point of $(x_n)$ but the converse is not true?

**Edit:**
There's been a lot of development in the comments so I'm updating this with what I've learned so far.

Intuitively, $l$ is a limit point of a sequence $(x_n)$ if and only if $l$ occurs in the sequence infinitely many times or there are infinitely many $x_n$s in $(l−ϵ,l+ϵ)\setminus \{l\}$ for every $\epsilon >0$

So in a way, definition $1 =$ definition $2$ $+$ $(x_n=l$, for infinitely many values of $n$).

Comment: Passing from a sequence to a set loses the “multiplicities” encoded in the sequence. (I.e. you can ask how often $x$ occurs in the sequence but not how often it occurs in the set.) (You also lose the order but that is irrelevant for questions of convergence.) So for a point to be the limit point of a set, there need to be a infinitely many *different* points of the set in each of its neighborhoods. For sequences “different” is not necessary (but note that the only way to use repetitions to get a limit point is to repeat the limit point itself).

Comment: @EikeSchulte I think your comment is not relevant, I understand both the definitions, I'm well aware that the two definitions are different. I'm not asking for explanations of the definitions. The purpose of these questions is I want to understand "just how much similar are they" and I figured a good way to do that is to understand just how different are they, really.

Comment: But the difference between the two definitions really is about the “multiplicities”. A point can be a limit point of a sequence because that point itself occurs in the sequence infinitely many times. For a limit point of a set you need infinitely many *different* points in each $(l-\epsilon, l+\epsilon)$.

Comment: Your reformulation in question 2 does work, because excluding $l$ and the fact that you require it for every $\epsilon$ forces there to be infinitely many *different* $x_n$ (i.e. the points $x_n$ are different, not just the indices $n$). Hence, your deduction after that question is correct, too.

Comment: More precisely: Every limit point of the range of a sequence is a limit point of the sequence. Conversely, a limit point of the sequence is a limit point of its range *unless* it is *only* a limit point of the sequence because it appears infinitely many times in the sequence.

Comment: @EikeSchulte I hear you, are you trying to say that, If $S$ is the range of $(x_n)$ then $l$ is a limit point of the *sequence* $(x_n)$ iff either $x_n=l$ for infinitely many values of $n$ **or** $(l- \epsilon,l+\epsilon)\cap S$ is infinite set? So in a way, definition 1 $=$ definition 2 $+$ ($x_n = l$ for infinitely many values of $n$)? Is that what you're suggesting? Well in that case how would you prove $(l- \epsilon,l+\epsilon)\cap S$ is infinite, or rather there are *infinitely many different* $x_n$s just using definition 1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you pass from a sequence $(x_n)$ to its range $S = \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$, you essentially forget two things:

- How often each element appears in the sequence. I will call this “multiplicity”.
- The order of the elements.

It turns out that losing the order is not important in this context (the limit points of a sequence don’t change when you reorder it) but the fact that you forget the multiplicity does.

Essentially, $l$ can be a limit point of a sequence $(x_n)$ in two different ways:

1. It might be the case that $l$ occurs in the sequence an infinite number of times.
2. There is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ consisting of *pairwise different* elements that converges to $l$. We can also make sure that $l$ is not an element of this sequence (if it is, simply drop that term which does not change the limit).

It is not completely obvious that one of these has to be true for every limit point, so let’s prove it:

Let $l$ be a limit point of $(x_n)$. If $l$ occurs infinitely often in $(x_n)$, we are in case 1. So assume that $l$ does not occur infinitely many times. For $\epsilon_1 = 1$, there are infinitely many $n$ such that $x_n \in (l - \epsilon_1, l + \epsilon_1)$. As $l$ occurs only finitely many times, some of these $x_n$ need to be different form $l$. Pick $n_1$ such that $x_{n_1} \in (l - \epsilon_1, l + \epsilon_1) \setminus \{l\}$.

Next, consider $\epsilon_2 = \min \{ \frac 1 2, |x_{n_1} - l| \}$. Again, we can pick, $n_2$ such that $x_{n_2} \in (l - \epsilon_2, l + \epsilon_2) \setminus \{l\}$. We can also make sure that $n_2 > n_1$.

In general, consider $\epsilon_k = \min \{ \frac 1 k, |x_{n_k} - l| \}$ and pick $n_k$ such that $$x_{n_k} \in (l - \epsilon_k, l + \epsilon_k) \setminus \{l\}$$ and $n_k > n_{k - 1}$.

This way, we get a subsequence $(x_{n_k})$ of $(x_n)$ such that $x_{n_{k + 1}}$ is closer to $l$ than $x_{n_k}$ (in particular, they’re all different), none of them is equal to $l$ and the subsequence converges to $l$ (the definition of $\epsilon_k$ with $\frac 1 k$ ensures that). QED

Note that both cases can occur simultaneously.

Now, if you pass to $S = \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ you lose the information about the multiplicity and hence you can’t whether see case 1 (for a given $l$) holds for the sequence from $S$ alone. You can see case 2 because the *pairwise different* elements of the subsequence give pairwise different elements of $S$.

We want the definitions of “limit point” to be somewhat compatible, so for the definition of limit points of a set, we have to decide what to do with case one. If we wanted to include case 1, we would have remove the “$\setminus \{l\}$” part from the definition you quoted at the beginning of your post. But then, *every* element of a set would be a limit point of that set. (Hence, when considering the range of a sequence, every element of the sequence would be a limit point of the range.) We don’t want that here (what you get this way is the “closure” of the set). So one uses the definition you cited.

What this means is that if for a limit point $l$ of $(x_n)$ *only* case 1 is true (remember that both might be true for $l$ at the same time) then $l$ is *not* a limit point of $S = \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. The limit points of $S$ are precisely those limit points of $(x_n)$ where case 2 is true. In particular, the limit points of $S$ form a subset of the limit points of $(x_n)$.

Let’s look at some examples:

1. The sequence $(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, \dots)$. Both $1$ and $0$ are limit points of the sequence. The range, however, is $\{1, 0\}$ and has no limit points at all.
2. The sequence $(1, 0, \frac 1 2, 0, \frac 1 3, 0, \frac 1 4, \dots)$. The only limit point of this sequence is $0$ and it fulfills both case 1 *and* case 2. Hence, $0$ is a limit point of the range as well (the range is $\{0, 1, \frac 1 2, \frac 1 3, \frac 1 4, \dots \}$).

**Edit.** Maybe the following argument is better: Let $l$ be a limit point of $(x_n)$ but not a limit point of $S = \{ x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$. Because $l$ is not a limit point of $S$, there is some $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(l - \epsilon, l + \epsilon) \setminus \{l\}$ contains no element of $S$, i.e. no $x_n$ at all. On the other hand, $l$ is a limit point of $(x_n)$. Therefore, $(l - \epsilon, l + \epsilon)$ must contain $x_n$ for infinitely many $n$. Because the only new point when going from $(l - \epsilon, l + \epsilon) \setminus \{l\}$ to $(l - \epsilon, l + \epsilon)$ is $l$, we must have $x_n = l$ for infinitely many $n$.

Comment: I understand your answer and follow your proof and reasoning. The only thing I'm unable to make sense out of is your 2nd case. "There is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ consisting of *pairwise different* elements that converges to $l$". I'm not sure I understand what that means, can you write this sentence using math symbols perhaps?

Comment: Intuitively, it was my understanding that $l$ is a limit point of a sequence $(x_n)$ if and only if $l$ occurs in the sequence infinitely many times or there are infinitely many $x_n$s in $(l-\epsilon , l+\epsilon) \setminus \{l\}$ for every $\epsilon >0$, is that what you meant by case 2?

Comment: It is kind of what I mean (it is true anyways, and turns out to be equivalent). What we need are infinitely many *(pairwise) different* elements because that will ensure that there are also infinitely many elements in the set $S$ (which we need for the definition of a limit point of a set). One way to get infinitely many different elements is to construct a sequence consisting of pairwise different elements (it being a sequence ensures that there are infinitely many).

Comment: It might be conceivable, that each $(l - \epsilon, l + \epsilon)$ contains infinitely many $x_n$ (by which I mean $x_n \in (l - \epsilon, l + \epsilon)$ for infinitely many different indices $n$) but only finitely many *different* $x_n$. And in fact, this can occur, but only if $x_n = l$ for infinitely many $n$ (this is case 1). By using $(l - \epsilon, l + \epsilon) \setminus \{l\}$ instead of $(l - \epsilon, l + \epsilon)$, we exclude this case. The argument in my answer shows that the only other way to get a limit point is by having infinitely many different points.

Comment: It is okay, by the way, if some of these points also repeat (even infinitely often). What’s important is that there are not just finitely many different points because they would not produce a limit point of $S$.

Comment: Ah ha I suspected that. I just wanted someone to confirm it, I scribbled around a little and I was actually able to come up with a proof of the second case when $x_n=l$ for finite number of $n$s, myself. See below. So indeed definition 1 = definition 2 + $x_n=l$ for infinitely many $n$s.

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering my own question, if there are any flaws in my reasoning, feel free to correct me.

It appears my Intuition was correct and here's my proof.

Given $l$ is a limit point, there could be only 2 reasons why $l$ is a limit point.

1. When $x_n=l$ for infinitely many values of $n$ then $x_n \in (l- \epsilon, l+\epsilon)$ for infinitely many values of $n$

**OR**

2. When $x_n=l$ for finite number of $n$s, in which case $((l- \epsilon, l+\epsilon)\setminus\{l\}) \cap S$ must be an infinite set.

**Proof:** $x_n=l$ for finite number of $n$ and since we know $l$ is a limit point so $x_n \in (l- \epsilon, l+\epsilon)$ for infinitely many $n$s
$\Rightarrow x_n \in (l- \epsilon, l+\epsilon) \setminus \{l\}$ for infinitely many $n$s. And now we can show that in this case there must be infinitely many $x_n$s using contradiction proof.

Assuming there are finite $x_n$s in $(l- \epsilon, l+\epsilon)$, name them $p_1, p_2, \ldots, p_k$

Let $\epsilon = \min \{|l-p_1|,|l-p_2|, \ldots, |l-p_k| \} >0$ then $((l- \epsilon, l+\epsilon)\setminus \{l\}) \cap S= \varnothing$ i.e there are no $x_n$s in $(l- \epsilon, l+\epsilon)$ which is a contradiction as it is a given that $l$ is a limit point so some $x_n$ must belong to $(l- \epsilon, l+\epsilon)$ for infinitely many $n$s. Therefore, $((l- \epsilon, l+\epsilon)\setminus\{l\})\cap S$ is infinite, that is there are infinitely many different $x_n$s in $(l- \epsilon, l+\epsilon)\setminus\{l\})$, which completes the proof.

The "**or**" disjunction covers the possibility of case 1 and 2 happening together.